# How do I use the StackExchange API from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, stackexchange-api

How do I access data from the StackExchange API using Matlab?

The naive

```
sitedata = urlread('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?tagged=matlab')
```

fails since the data is compressed. However, when I write this to file (using `fprintf(fileID,'%s',sitedata)`), I get a zip-file that cannot be uncompressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `urlwrite()` instead:

```
urlwrite('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/questions?tagged=matlab',...
  'tempfile.zip')
gunzip('tempfile.zip')
fid = fopen('tempfile');
str = textscan(fid,'%s',Delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);
```

A better version of this snippet would use `tempname` to dynamically generate temporary filenames.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work quite nicely. Note that the `textscan` line will produce a 1-by-lots string for the 2.1 interface, thought that's a good thing if you want to extract data via regexp afterward.

Answer (score 3):

Matlab's `urlread` assumes you're getting text data back, not binary. The gzip binary data is getting mangled either when `urlread` is decoding the character data to Unicode values to stick in Matlab `char`s, or when the formatted-output `fprintf` function is writing them out, encoding them to UTF-8 or whatever default character encoding you're using for `fileID` and changing the byte sequence, or maybe both.

IIRC, `urlread` will default to using ISO-8859-1 encoding, which means the bytes will be turned in to the Unicode code points with the same numeric values - effectively just a widening. So you can get the byte data back by doing `sitebytes = uint8(sitedata)`. (That's a regular `uint8()` conversion, not a `typecast()`.) (If this isn't the case, you can probably fiddle with `urlread`'s `CharSet` option.)

If you can't get the right bytes out from `urlread` by fiddling with the encoding and casts, then you can drop down and make calls against the Java `HttpAgent` like `urlread` does and bypass the character set decoding step, or fiddle with its options. See the `urlread` source for how to do it.

Once you have the right bytes in memory, you can write them out to a file using the lower-level `fwrite()` function, which won't mangle them by doing character set encoding. Then you'll have a valid gzip file of the site's original response. (I think it'll work if you also just use `fwrite(fileID, sitedata, 'uint8')` directly on the char string, but it's uglier IMHO.)

You can also unzip it in memory using Java classes and save a trip to the filesystem. Do `jsitebytes = typecast(sitebytes 'int8')` to get them as Java-friendly signed bytes and then stick it into a `ByteArrayInputStream` and read it out through a `GZIPInputStream`. You'll need to build a little Java helper class because Matlab doesn't play well with passing `byte[]` buffers by reference like `java.io` wants, but it may be worthwhile if you do a lot of in-memory munging like this.

When working with web services or fancier data downloads (e.g. sites that need sessions or certificates), I've often ended up dropping down and coding directly against the `HttpAgent` and `java.io` classes from within Matlab.

Comment: Actually, I looked at the `urlread` help page and it looks like it defaults to using UTF-8 encoding. So you might have to set it to ISO-8859-1 or drop down to Java to get this to work. (Reading UTF-8 and then fprintfing UTF-8 might seem like you'd end up with the same file, but if the input had invalid or non-canonical byte sequences, they could get rendered as different bytes in the output. Or a sequence of 0s might cause truncated output.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! It looks like the `urlwrite` approach is simpler for this particular problem, but I've just learned a lot about interacting with web services!